# Area of the region bounded by $r = |\sin \theta|$

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to find the area of the region bounded by $r =|\sin \theta | $ in the $xy$-plane using the formula: 
\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} (|\sin \theta|)^2 d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} (1-\cos2\theta)^2 d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} (1-2\cos\theta + \cos^22\theta)^2 d\theta \\
\end{align*}

which I get $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as the answer but I got it wrong on a test.

The other options are:

1. $\frac{\pi}{2}$
2. $\frac{\pi}{4}$
3. $\pi$
4. $1$
5. $2$

Could there have been a mistake on the test or did I miss something?

Comment: $1-\cos(2\theta) = 2 \sin^2\theta$.

Comment: The other problem is that your integral does not get you the full area. $r=\sin\theta$ is a circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$, but $r=|\sin\theta|$ is two circles.

Comment: @leastaction even putting the first line in symbolab gives me $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Somehow, your incorrect manipulation got the correct result for the integral, an example of two mistakes canceling each other out. Even still, the limits of integration are wrong, it should be from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the area integral is

$$A=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{|\sin(\theta)|} rdrd\theta
=\frac12  \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2\theta d\theta
=\frac14  \int_0^{2\pi} (1-\cos2\theta )d\theta=\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 0):

The Cartesian equation for $r=\sin\theta$ is given by

$$x^2 + \left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$

however the Cartesian equation for $r=|\sin\theta|$ is given by two circles, not one, of the form

$$x^2 + \left(y\pm\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$

Thus the area bounded by this polar curve in the $xy$-plane is twice the area of one circle, $2\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Desmos graph to see which step in your integration process is wrong: 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9wklwenvqf